# is this the correct site for feedback?

Tags: discussion

okay, so my partner has recently started poetry, and although i tell her its good, she wont believe me, and she is too shy to show anyone else, so i was thinking of sneaking some to get some feedback to rack up her confidence, would this be possible here or is there a good website that gives feedback?

she also enjoys doing short stories that are always extremely descriptive.

I hope someone can help, many thanks

Comment: "i was thinking of sneaking some to get some feedback" - Keep in mind that posting the writing of someone else without their permission is violating their copyright. I'd guess it's also against the [Stack Exchange TOS](https://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service).

Comment: I agree with SF's answer.  An additional thing you can try on this site if you're looking for more-general feedback is to come into [chat].  Put the piece up on some other web site rather than pasting it all in there (also addresses the SE TOS issue).  No guarantees, but people in chat sometimes review each other's work, so you could try to get in on that (on both sides).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have a fairly specific set of rules concerning feedback/criticism here. Yes, criticism requests are welcome here, but they MUST be focused. We don't provide general criticism, "what we think", "what we like", "what we believe could be improved". You won't get any constructive answers if you ask "is this a good poem?"

We do provide specific criticism of chosen aspects of writing. Do you want to know if the poem succeeds in surprising the reader? Is the rich stylization tasteful or gaudy? Does this exception in meter create a special moment of focus or just spoils the flow? Does this slow pace create tension, or does it bore? Can you find the hidden message about war, or did I hide it too deep?

(and the specifics of this site are that you will likely get some general criticism on top of the detailed answer - if you ask the focused question. If you ask "what can I improve", "is it any good" or "what would you have done better", you'll get the question closed as non-constructive.)

Comment: ah brilliant, makes it pretty clear. Thanks for the answer @SF